# How to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$ or $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \sqrt{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to solve either of the following integrals, they are related to each other by integration by parts:

$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$

or

$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \sqrt{1+x^2}dx$$

I have not been able to find them in integral tables and I wonder if it is possible to solve either of these integrals.

Any ideas on how to calculate $I_1$ or $I_2$?

Comment: Are you confident with Bessel and Struve functions?

Comment: put $x=\sinh(t)$ then you obtain

$$
I_1=\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-a\sinh(t))\sinh(t)
$$
then have a look here 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5 and here http://dlmf.nist.gov/11.4

Comment: No. I know how to solve it in terms of these, but I would like to have a function as a solution, not another integral or infinite sum @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @Mencia: $Y_1(z)$ **is** a function. It also equals an infinite series, just like $e^z$ equals $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n!}$.

Comment: $I_2=\frac{1}{a}(I_1-1)$

Comment: @tired yes, I mentioned they are related by integration by parts.

Comment: togehter with my first comment, your question is answered

Comment: @tired I can see I can get a solution as function of the Struve function $K_0$, but then I am still left with an infinite sum which is not helpful.

Comment: what else have you expected? there is nothing simpler then this (at least well studied) function. you are lucky, most integrals don't have this relativly easy form

Comment: @tired I wanted to know whether there is simple expression for it. It seems like is not the case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}~dx$ ,

$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-a\sinh t}\dfrac{\sinh t}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}}~d(\sinh t)$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-a\sinh t}\sinh t~dt$

$=-\dfrac{d}{da}\int_0^\infty e^{-a\sinh t}~dt$

$=-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\dfrac{d}{da}\mathbf{K}_0(a)$ (according to https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5)

For $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sqrt{1+x^2}~dx$ ,

$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sqrt{1+x^2}~dx=\dfrac{\pi\mathbf{K}_1(a)}{2a}$ (according to https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.5)

Answer (score -2):

If you notice it, you will see that this is the form of Laplace transformation. Thus the first integration can be written as the Laplace transformation of (x/root(x^2 +1))
The second integral can be written by integration by parts
Which is e^-ax * root(x^2 +1) - integrate(-ae^-at * root(x^2 +1) dx)
Which is then equals to 
e^-ax * root(x^2 +1) + a*laplace of (root(x^2 +1))

Hope this helped

Comment: how does this answer helps the op?